# Adding source files to project according definition

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I would like include some source `.cpp` and `.h` files to my project according definition. Code (cpp+h) that needs to be included is located in separate directory called `aaa`. `VC` compiles my code when `cpp` and `h` files are included in project explorer. How to tell `VC` to include files for compilation with help of definitions or something like that? I need this feature to control included code with `#ifdef` options.

Actually it is quite easy to solve problem with headers by setting `Configuration Properties>>C/C++>>General>>Additional Include Directories` by defining to `aaa`
But how to make `VC` compile my `cpp` files from `aaa` location?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to wrap whole cpp files content with macros to control whether code should be included into compilation.

For example if you have a.cpp and b.cpp both in VC project. If you want to exclude b.cpp then

1. add #ifndef B_IS_EXCLUDED in the begin and #endif at the end of a b.cpp file.
2. Add B_IS_EXCLUDED into Properties>>C/C++>>Preprcessor>>PreprocessoerDefinitions